# How to define composite keys with dbDelta()

Tags: database, mysql, wpdb, dbdelta

I am getting error while trying to create a table with `dbDelta()` and composite primary key. The sql is pretty straight forward.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}voicemail_call (

    user_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    call_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    opened BOOL DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY  (user_id, call_id)
    );";

dbDelta($sql);
```

**This shows error**

```
WordPress database error: [Multiple primary key defined]
ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, call_id)
```

Am I doing it wrong? How to correctly defined composite primary key with dbDelta?

**Note:** Although error is shown but it still creates the table where both columns are set as primary key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The problem

If the table already exists your code will still try to execute the following queries:

```
1) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call CHANGE COLUMN user_id user_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
2) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call CHANGE COLUMN call_id call_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
3) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call CHANGE COLUMN opened opened BOOL DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
4) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call ADD 
5) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, call_id)
```

Note that this query:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, call_id)
```

is trying to add another primary key that's already defined and we can only have of one of those. Thus the error.

This query:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call ADD
```

comes from the **empty line** above the `PRIMARY KEY` line.

In the `dbDelta()` function there's [this part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f9bba421b588cba59fd5bd00020b6fee3d2d50c3/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L2285-L2292) that should unset the primary parts:

```
foreach ( $index_strings as $index_string ) {
    if ( ! ( ( $aindex = array_search( $index_string, $indices ) ) === false ) ) {
        unset( $indices[ $aindex ] );
        break
     }
}
```

but the array search always return false in your case for some reason.

I dug deeper and in your case the `$indices` array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => PRIMARY KEY  (user_id, call_id)
)
```

but the `$index_strings` array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => PRIMARY KEY  (user_id,call_id)
    [1] => PRIMARY KEY  (user_id,call_id)
)
```

So we can see the mismatch:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (user_id,call_id)
```

versus

```
PRIMARY KEY  (user_id, call_id)
```

... a single space!!

### The suggested solution

So if we remove the extra empty line and the extra space:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}voicemail_call (
    user_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    call_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    opened BOOL DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (user_id,call_id)
);";
```

then we should only get these queries to run with `dbDelta()`:

```
1) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call CHANGE COLUMN user_id user_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
2) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call CHANGE COLUMN call_id call_id BIGINT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
3) ALTER TABLE wp_voicemail_call CHANGE COLUMN opened opened BOOL DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

when the table already exists.

Comment: An empty line and a space. God bless us!

Comment: Using `dbDelta()` is like "feeding the crocodiles", we have to be very careful ;-) @Sisir